# How do I inject the execution context in a AbstractModule in play?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I'm using the playframework, and I am trying to inject the execution context inside of a AbstractModule:

```scala
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provider}
     
    import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provider}
    import javax.inject.Inject

    class MyModule @Inject() (environment: Environment, config: Configuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractModule {
      override def configure(): Unit = {
          // ..
      }
    }
```

I get a runtime error:

> No valid constructors Module [...MyModule] cannot be constructed

This works fine but I am referencing the ExecutionContext using the global which I don't want to (in fact I need to reference a named EC once I get this working)

```scala
     import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provider}
     import javax.inject.Inject
     import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    
      class MyModule @Inject() (environment: Environment, config: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {
          override def configure(): Unit = {
              // ..
          }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try by defining the `ExecutionContext` in the 1st parameter list along with `environment` and `config`? (Just a guess..)

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes I did, same error.

Answer (score 0):

*Nerco'ing an old post for future reference.*

Now, I am sure my post below is riddled with both errors and misconceptions so take this with a gain of salt.

As for the second example:

```
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provider}
import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class MyModule @Inject() (environment: Environment, config: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
          // ..
  }
}
```

Speaking, very generally, in the context of Play here, using `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is sort of an anti-pattern (ignoring that fact that you did not even want to use the global execution context in the first place), especially while the Play framework supplies one for general use. I usually only use the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` during tests unless I for some reason should need a different one.

As for the first example and the original question:

```
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provider}
import javax.inject.Inject

class MyModule @Inject() (environment: Environment, config: Configuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
      // ..
  }
}
```

This, as you know, will not work nor is there any way (that I know of) to make it work as you want. The reason is, that

1. there is no constructor actually matching the signature of `class MyModule @Inject() (environment: Environment, config: Configuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)`
2. as far as I understand it (which is not unlikely to be wrong), at this point of time in the application life cycle, no actual bindings have been made for dependency injection yet (apart from those for `environment` and `configuration` which are special cases).

Try looking at it this way: At this point in time, Guice (used by default for dependency injection in Play) is aggregating a list of bindings in order to create a dependency graph. This dependency graph used to figure out which object instances that must be present in order to create other object instances (I need to create A but A requires B and C and C requires D, so I must do D before C then C and B before A).

What you are essentially asking Play and Guice to do, is create an instance of a class by using a constructor that does not exist and inject components into it that it is on the process of figuring out how to create.